# Creating employee Id card with barcode in CodeIgniter

Tags: image, codeigniter

I already created barcode image and employee ID card structure,but I don't know how to merge employee photo, barcode,card structure with text like his name.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. Show piece of your code (can be abstract) and write what kind of result you are expecting.

Comment: i need one image to be created using Codeignitor ,which should have his barcode,his name and his photo

Comment: Provide us the code? Controller, model. view.